# Citations appearing as "1111"

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Using biber and pdflatex, all my citations appear as "1111, year" instead of "First author year". For example the following code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,
uniquelist=false,
bibstyle=publist,
plnumbered=false,
marginyear=true,
plauthorhandling=highlight,
boldyear=false,
url=true,
sorting=ydnt,
natbib=true,
minnames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
minbibnames=7,
maxbibnames=8,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
Citation: ``\cite{kimm_towards_2015}''.
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

where the bibliography is

```
@article{kimm_towards_2015,
  title = {Towards Simulating Star Formation in Turbulent High-z Galaxies with Mechanical Supernova Feedback},
  volume = {451},
  doi = {10.1093/mnras/stv1211},
  abstract = {Blabla},
  number = {3},
  journal = {Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society},
  author = {Kimm, Taysun and Cen, Renyue and Devriendt, Julien and Dubois, Yohan and Slyz, Adrianne},
  year = {2015},
  keywords = {Galaxies: formation,Galaxies: high-redshift,Galaxies: ISM},
  pages = {2900-2921},
}
```

shows

```
Citation: “1111, 2015”.
```

Do you have any idea of what is happening? Note that I have the same issue when using another bibliography file and citing another paper, so the issue doesn't seem to come from the .bib. file.

---

I run on (Arch)Linux with the following versions

```
$ biber --version
biber version: 2.12
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.35; using libpng 1.6.35
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 0.71.0
```

Comment: This seems to be an interaction of the combination of the publist bibstyle and the authoryear style. Which style do you actually want? Both have very different purposes.

Comment: You're right. If I set everything to publist or to authoryear, this works. However is their a way to have inline citations with the format `author et al. year` with the bibliography using the publist style?

Comment: I'm having this problem too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`biblatex-publist` is a bibliography style specifically designed for lists of publications of a specific author (in CVs or similar documents). It is not really intended for use with citations, though `biblatex-publist` offers a dummy citation style based on `numeric`.

It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve, but I would strongly suggest to drop `publist` if you are writing a normal bibliography/list of references instead of a list of publications. There are other styles like [`biblatex-philosophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy) that let you produce fancy output with years to the left of entries.

The specific problem here is that `biblatex-publist` sets the `shortauthor` field to "1111" in order to control sorting. That means that the `labelname` comes out as "1111". You can undo that with

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[
style=authoryear,
uniquelist=false,
bibstyle=publist,
plnumbered=false,
marginyear=true,
plauthorhandling=highlight,
boldyear=false,
url=true,
sorting=ydnt,
natbib=true,
minnames=1,
maxcitenames=2,
minbibnames=7,
maxbibnames=8,
backend=biber
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \step[fieldsource=shortauthor, match=\regexp{\A1111\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=shortauthor, null]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
Citation: ``\cite{sigfridsson}''.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citation: “Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998”.]

Please note that `biblatex-publist` overwrites any existing contents in the `shortauthor` field and this code can't bring the overwritten contents back. So the output can not be guaranteed to be as expected with other styles.

You may meet many more rough edges or counter-intuitive results along the way. `biblatex-publist` does some clever modifications to obtain the desired results, but that is not always compatible with all possible citation styles.